# Dynamodb secondary indexes latency for realtime updates

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I am wondering if Amazon Dynamodb Global secondary indexes can be used for a realtime application with very heavy writes. Ex: Chat application.
where global secondary indexes need to be updated in sub-millisecond latency as soon the main table write/update is done. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 5):

With those requirements, at this time, no. While DynamoDB can handle VERY heavy write throughput, the data currently will replicate from the table to the GSI in single digit millisecond latency, not sub-millisecond. Just make sure you get your data model correct.

Comment: Single digit millisecond latency would work for chat applications. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Cool. you had just said sub-millisecond as well.